# How to disable Authorization Required before loading wp-admin page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website and i tried to log in to wp-admin page but then suddenly an Authentication Required pop out screen appeared. I did not set up it so I didn't know the credentials. what should i need to do so i can proceed with the wp-admin page log in screen?

[image: Here is the authentication required pop out screen.]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to .htaccess file

Satisfy Any

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can access you WP admin without a password- that would put your site security at risk. You should contact the person who built your site and ask them to make you the site admin or alternatively send you the admin credentials.

More info can be found here: 
https://plugins.cminds.com

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Try looking at the question twice before you are giving an answer, The screen shot shows you it is not the wordpress login, they are asked about

Comment: I'm sorry I know it can't. but my problem is that before going to the login screen of wordpress 
which is supposedly like this.
http://i.imgur.com/1fJ5Wmp.jpg

the authentication pop out screen is displaying.